# Obter valor da semana que vai começar um mês

Tags: php

Quero obter o valor da semana,em que vai comecar um determinado mês. Funciona para o mês actual, mas quero para os restantes meses. Este é o codigo que utilizei para calcular, em que day é o dia de hoje.

```
$day = date("d");
$numjour = date("N",time()-(($day-1)*3600*24));
```

Comment: Com valor da semana você quis dizer o dia da semana que vai ser o dia 1º do certo mês? Por exemplo, o atual mês de novembro teve o dia 1 num sábado. Você quer que ele te retorne "Sábado"?

Comment: Mas se você setar `$day` para o dia que começa o mês ele te retornara a semana.

Comment: Por exemplo para hoje, o resultado é 6 que é sexta feira.

Comment: Quero que me da o resultado para outros meses, alterando um codigo para uma variavel $mes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [date()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php) para este objetivo. Ao passar a opção 'w' ele retorna o número da semana de um certo dia.

Primeiro você transforma a data em *timestamp*, com a função `strtotime();`. O formato da data vai ser  `$mes . "/01/" . date('Y')`, ou seja, o primeiro dia do mês `$mes` do ano atual. Observe que a data está no formato americano "mes/dia/ano".

Então você passa esse `timestamp` para a função `date()` com a opção 'w' que retorna o número do dia da semana correspondente àquela data.

```
function primeiroDiaDoMes($mes) {
    $dia =  (int) date("w", strtotime($mes . "/01/" . date('Y')));
    return $dia;
}
echo primeiroDiaDoMes("11");
```

Exemplo: http://codepad.org/QJvxuuMQ

Vai imprimir '6', pois o mês de novembro começou em um sábado, que é representado pelo número 6. Domingo é representado em '0'.